# Plot on higher time frame. Security, mutable variable, global variable, function problem

Tags: function, security, pine-script, mutable

I'm trying to plot the same shape from the 15 min onto the Daily as well. This is the code to plot a shape on the 15 min which works fine;

```
if crossover(s3K,s3D) and s3K<25 and (s4K-s4D<3 and s4K-s4D>-3) and s4K<35//or s4D-s4K>0 and s4D-s4K<1 and s4K<50 and s1K<40
      rwCross:=true
plotshape(rwCross, style = shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar, color=color.yellow, size=size.small)
```

But to plot it on the daily i've tried;

```
rwCrossDaily = security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', rwCross)
plotshape(rwCrossDaily, style = shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar, color=color.yellow, size=size.small)
```

Which gives me the mutable variable error. So i tried using a function to get around it;

```
rwCross_func() =>
  if crossover(s3K,s3D) and s3K<25 and (s4K-s4D<3 and s4K-s4D>-3) and s4K<35//or s4D-s4K>0 and s4D-s4K<1 and s4K<50 and s1K<40
    rwCross:=true
rwCrossDaily = security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', rwCross_func())
```

But now it tells me I 'Cannot modify global variable 'rwCross' in function.'
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution and cleanest solution here is to just make a bool out of your condition in its simplest form:

```
rwCross = crossover(s3K,s3D) and s3K<25 and (s4K-s4D<3 and s4K-s4D>-3) and s4K<35//or s4D-s4K>0 and s4D-s4K<1 and s4K<50 and s1K<40
```

rwCross will naturally become true without the if. This way we do not need to have anything mutable, although there are more solutions for situations that we must...

Cheers!